# JasperServer management page does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jasperserver

I installed JasperServer 6.2.1 Community Edition by its installer from http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-server/releases .

When I try to connect management page at http://localhost:8081/jasperserver/login.html, it does not work as it should be. It's CSS and Javascript functionalities are broken as displayed below.

Is there any solution to this?

[image: image1]

Answer (score 1):

In jasperserver CSS files can be located on ***{your tomcat directory}/webapps/jasperserver/*** or in the jasperserver database (***jiresoirce*** table). You can choose where to take CSS files in ***applicationContext-themes.xml*** (*{your tomcat directory}/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF*). When you open the file you would see a comment. Try to follow it. But firstly reinstall database and check jiresoirce table if it contains resources.

PS. Please, attach chrome Developer Tools Network tab. I suppose there can be a lot of useful logs.

Comment: Thank you very much @V. Spachynskyi ! I need your answer again.

Comment: In addition, I give Full Permission to Autenticated User for apache-tomcat folder in Jasperserver installation(C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-cp-6.3.0\apache-tomcat). Maybe it make contrubiton for the solution, too.